# onClick in imageView in ListView

Tags: android, events

I need to define an `onClick()` event in an arrow image inside a `ListView`. This arrow moves to another screen (another activity).

I have read information about `setOnItemClickListener()`, but I can not use this, because I need the `onClick()` event in the arrow `ImageView`, not in the item in general.

I also have read to define an `OnClickListener` in the `ImageView` in my custom `BaseAdapter`, but the problem is that I use functions of the `Activity`, that I can not use in the `BaseAdapter` (because don't exist, obviously)

```
right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ByLocationList.this, Summary.class);
            startActivity(i);               

        }
    });
```

I got errors because there is no `startActivity()` in `BaseAdapter` class. How can I launch the Summary Activity?

Comment: I'm not really sure about your design approach here and I'm not confident that you have the recommended architecture - but either way - have you tried using the context from your view, ie `arg0.getContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got errors because there is no startActivity() in BaseAdapter class.
>   How can I launch the Summary Activity?

=> Pass **context** of current activity as an argument in constructor of your BaseAdapter class.

For example:

```
private Context context;
public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JSONObject> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_listView, data);

        this.context = context;
        ........
        ........
    }
```

And then start activity by using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Summary.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It is "normal" to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityClassName.this, Summary.class); // not the name of your adapter
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

public void sum (View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Summary.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
    }

put android:onClick="sum" on your image

Comment: Why should someone use global context of application? Especially just for adapter.